# How to make a delay in assembly for avr microcontrollers?

Tags: assembly, delay, microcontroller, atmel

I am having a problem in calculating delays. I want to make a delay for `1 sec` when I am using `1MHz` clock speed for my atmega128 microcontroller.

I use proteus for simulation and avr studio for coding in assembly for atmel microcontroller.

For example this code is for `8MHz` clock microcontroller

```
Delay_15mS:                 ; For CLK(CPU) = 8 MHz
    LDI     dly1,   120     ; One clock cycle;
Delay1:
    LDI     dly2,   250     ; One clock cycle
Delay2:
    DEC     dly2            ; One clock cycle
    NOP                     ; One clock cycle
    BRNE    Delay2          ; Two clock cycles for true 1 clock for false

    DEC     dly1            ; One clock Cycle
    BRNE    Delay1          ; Two clock cycles for true 1 clock for false
RET
```

Can you teach me how to calculate the time this delay will take? So I could make 1 for 1 sec delay @ 1 MHz

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Delay in Arduino Uno using Assembly language without using timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477849/create-delay-in-arduino-uno-using-assembly-language-without-using-timer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To calculate a delay, you need to calculate the cycle time and then count how may cycles you need to reach the wanted delay.

In your case, `1MHz` clock means `1000000` cycles per second. So `1` cycle equals `1/1000000` seconds or `1us`. To get 1 second delay, you need `1000000` cycles of `1us`, so it means that you have to create an algorithm of `1000000` cycles.

Building on your example, a `1` sec delay `@ 1MHz` clock would be:

```
Delay_1sec:                 ; For CLK(CPU) = 1 MHz
    LDI     dly1,   8       ; One clock cycle;
Delay1:
    LDI     dly2,   125     ; One clock cycle
Delay2:
    LDI     dly3,   250     ; One clock cycle
Delay3:
    DEC     dly3            ; One clock cycle
    NOP                     ; One clock cycle
    BRNE    Delay3          ; Two clock cycles when jumping to Delay3, 1 clock when continuing to DEC

    DEC     dly2            ; One clock cycle
    BRNE    Delay2          ; Two clock cycles when jumping to Delay2, 1 clock when continuing to DEC

    DEC     dly1            ; One clock Cycle
    BRNE    Delay1          ; Two clock cycles when jumping to Delay1, 1 clock when continuing to RET
RET
```

In this case there is the internal loop `Delay3` that is `4` cycles long because `DEC=1`, `NOP=1` and `BRNE=2` when jumping to Delay3. So, `4` cycles repeated `250` times (the value of `dly3`) are `1000` cycles or `1000us` = `1ms`.

Then the loop `Delay2` repeats the `Delay3` `125` times (the value of `dly2`). So the accumulated delay in this case is `125ms`.

And finally, the loop `Delay1` repeats the `Delay2` `8` times (the value of `dly1`). So the accumulated delay in this case is `1000ms` or `1` second.

NOTE: This example delay is actually a little bit longer than `1sec` because I didn't consider the time of the instructions of `Delay2` and `Delay1`. The influence is very small, but for a precise `1sec` delay, these instructions must be counted and the values of `dly1`, `dly2` and `dly3` must be adjusted to guarantee that the algorithm is exactly `1000000` cycles long.

NOTE2: With this algorithm the microcontroller can't do anything else while executing the delay because you are using it to count cycles. If you want to do other things while doing a delay, take a look at [timers](https://www.newbiehack.com/TimersandCountersDefaultandBasicUsage.aspx) and interrupts of the microcontroller.

Comment: Did it work for you? If so, please do not forget to update and accept the answer! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use timer/counter for this. You can use timer/counter0 with `prescalar=1024` and `1MHz` clock for creating `250ms` delay. Each `250` milliseconds one interrupt will be generated. `4` interrupts mean `1` second!