# How to implement in-line assembly "for" loop in Arduino for faster delayMicros function

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr

I'm trying to make a more precise version of the Arduino's delayMicroseconds() function, the ultimate goal being a square-wave generator whose frequency can be varied up to 100 KHz with a precision of 0.2 KHz.

Based on the resources I found online, this was my best attempt:

```
  __asm__ ("mov eax, $x");
  __asm__("beginning:");
  __asm__("inc eax");
  __asm__("cmp eax, 0x0A");
  __asm__("jne beginning");
  __asm__("mov $x, eax");
```

I inputted the above code into the Arduino IDE and hit "verify;" the following error messages appeared:

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Uno"

C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:46: Error: constant value required
 C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:46: Error: constant value required
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:46: Error: unknown opcode `x'
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:54: Error: constant value required
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:58: Error: unknown opcode `cmp'
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:62: Error: unknown opcode `jne'
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:66: Error: constant value required
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:66: Error: `,' required
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:66: Error: constant value required
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:66: Error: garbage at end of line
C:\Users\212455~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cciNDaW0.s:66: Error: unknown opcode `x'
Error compiling.

This report would have more information with "Show verbose output during compilation" enabled in File > Preferences.
```

What should I do?

Comment: That is x86 assembly code, not avr ... maybe see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23478769/547981) for an example.

Comment: If all you want is a square wave then why not use PWM?

Comment: erm... the ultimate ULTIMATE goal is to output two square waves of the same frequency but offset by a phase shift of 90 degrees

Comment: I think your Arduino needs a 50MHz clock, and your delays need single clock precision, to achieve your stated objective of 0.2KHz precision at 100KHz.

Comment: that example looks like it's basically what i'm trying to do -- but i'm not sure how to implement it. they said it's in assembly... doesn't that mean i should use the "__asm__()" function?

Comment: That is how you specify assembly language. But that is not assembly language for the Arduino.

Comment: oh wait, i got a step further. i think i have to get around the fact that i'm trying to use "loop:" in the assembly code but it's already a defined function

Comment: oh. i see. you're saying i should be using avr? isn't that just c?

Comment: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0856.pdf

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams pointed you to the AVR instruction set, so you can use those assembly mnemonics. Moreover I think you are using the parameters (`$x`) in the wrong way (but I never used them, so I'm not sure). Try reading also this: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `_delay_loop_1()` and/or `_delay_loop_2()`, from
[avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay__basic.html).
The first one can count up to 256 and takes 3 cycles per iteration, for
a maximum of 768 cycles. The second one counts up to 65536 and takes 4
cycles per iteration, for a maximum of 262144 cycles.

If you look at the header file `util/delay_basic.h`,
you will see these are implemented as very simple inline assembly (2
instructions each).